# How to do less than equal to for date in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

When I try to run the below query I get no result even though the date time is same as that in the table.

The BillDateTime column is of TEXT Data type

```
SELECT * FROM BillingTransaction WHERE BillDateTime <= datetime('2021-09-19 07:21:31.371766')
```

| BillNo | VechicleNo | BillDateTime | LoadType | BillAmount | FirstWeight | SecondWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ka04sdfl | 2021-09-19 07:21:31.371766 | EMPTY | 30 | 400 | 0 |

Comment: @KenWhite `datetime()` does not convert a string to date because there is no date/ datetime data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 1):

The function [`datetime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) strips off everything after the seconds, because it is equivalent to:

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)
```

The result of:

```
SELECT datetime('2021-09-19 07:21:31.371766')
```

is:

```
2021-09-19 07:21:31
```

So your code is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM BillingTransaction WHERE BillDateTime <= '2021-09-19 07:21:31'
```

and this is why you don't get any rows.

You don't need the function `datetime()`, because the values of the column `BillDateTime` are strings in the proper ISO format.

You can do direct comparisons with them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BillingTransaction 
WHERE BillDateTime <= '2021-09-19 07:21:31.371766'
```